# pytest mock multiple request in one function

Tags: python, pytest

I try to write a test case for one of my functions. The function look like the following:

```
def function(self):
    token = self.request_post_get_token()
    self.request_post_1(token)
    self.request_post_2(token)
    return 200
```

each request_post test is a post request call, and it will return 200 or 401.
how to mock each post request call and return 200 and be able to let me test the whole function?

I'm using pytest and patch.object. Here is something I wrote, but I feel like I did it totally wrong.

```
def test_function():
    Response = nameTuple('Response', 'status_code text')
    r = Response(200, "test")
    with patch.object(request, 'post', return_value = r):
        self.request_post_get_token()
        with patch.object(requests, 'post', return_value = r):
            self.request_post_1("token")
                with patch.object(requests, 'post', return_value = r):
                self.request_post_2("token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching it the wrong way. When you write a test for a function it should only test the function itself, not all the functions it calls during it's run.

What you want to do is to mock the functions `request_post_2` and `request_post_1` and to check if they were called with the token using the function `assert_called_once`

Here is a quick example for you

```
# Arrange
cls_obj = YourClass()
cls_obj.request_post_2 = Mock()
cls_obj.request_post_1 = Mock()

# Act
cls_obj.function()

# Assert
cls_obj.request_post_2.assert_called_with_once(token)
cls_obj.request_post_1.assert_called_with_once(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each request is in some way unique ie no duplicate requests with different returns, you can register multiple request matchers which will return different results for each request. https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matching.html